# How is Teruah connected to friendship and closeness

Tags: commentaries, shofar, parashat-balak

I came across [this](http://download.yutorah.org/2013/1053/796903.pdf) article from which I would like to quote something:

> The concept of *Malchuso b'khal adaso* allows *Bnei Yisroel* to transform the *teruah* from a destructive sound of war into a sound that shows the friendship and love between *HaKadosh Baruch Hu* and *Knesses Yisroel*. The root of the word "רעה" means "friend", as *Elokim horoeh osi me'odi*, G-d who has been my shepherd (Breishis 48:15, see the Ramban ad loc.). This, indeed, is the *teruah* of "*u'teruas Melech bo*, the blast for the King is among them" (Bamidbar 23:21) mentioned in the verses of the *Malhiyos* blessing. This connotes closeness and intimacy between *Ribbono Shel Olam* and *Bnei Yisroel* and is proof that we are priviledged to have *HaKadosh Baruch Hu* as a friend. This is not *din* but rather *rachamim*, mercy.

With this new given meaning of teruah: "teruah" denotes a sense of kinship and closeness. Bamidbar 23:21 “*He perceived no iniquity in Jacob, and saw no perversity in Israel. Hashem his God is with him, u’teru’at Melech bo*” (Bamidbar 23:21). Rashi renders this last phrase as “and the friendship of the King is in him,” since, he explains, the word teru’ah is a derivative of the Hebrew word re’ut, friendship.

Is this what 'the shout of a King amongst them' or 'shouting for the King is among them' or 'And their King’s acclaim in their midst' means? **Why is this friendship or closeness specifically connected with the sound of a Shofar in the form of a Teruah blast**?

I didn't understand these explanations quite well, so maybe someone could explain it more clearly to me.

Comment: "Why is this friendship or closeness specifically connected with the sound of a Shofar in the form of a Teruah blast?" - I found a somewhat "unconventional" article that explains the term *Yom Teru'ah* and not the specific sound of the shofar that we know as *teru'ah*, i.e. the 9 short sounds. Is your question focused on the specific type of sound, or more generally regarding the word *teruah* and the sounding of the shofar in general.

Comment: @DanF Isn't Yom Teru'ah named after the blowing of the shofar? But to answer your question, I'm reffering to the word teruah. The question could have been about why the word teruah is chosen for one type of sound of shofar, while it also refers to closness and friendship; what's the common denomitor? I'm trying to figure out the connection that's been made in these commentaries en the other meanings of the word teru'ah.

Comment: @DanF found this: 
The word teru’ah, of course, conjures up the image of the blowing of the shofar. With our new understanding of the symbolic significance of the blowing of the shofar, we can easily connect the two interpretations of the word teru’ah (Rashi’s “friendship,” and our “shofar-blowing”): If, as we suggest, the blowing [teru’ah] of the shofar is symbolic of God’s blowing of a Godly soul into the first human, then the phrase teru’at Melech, “the blowing by the King,” takes on new significance:

Comment: @DanF...  teru’at Melech is a reference to the Godly soul, and Balaam is praising the nation because its members recognize and relate to the Godly soul within every human being – that is, the “blowing by the King which is within.” Thus, the Jewish people enjoys “the friendship of the King” (TERU'AT MELECH BO) because it recognizes and actualizes “the Godly soul each person possesses” (TERU'AT MELECH BO), the existence of which is affirmed by the shofar-blowing.

Comment: @DanF what's your view on this, is this a possible link?

Comment: It seems like you found far more comprehensive information than I did, and it looks like it answers your own question. I don't see this as an easily answerable question. I'm unaware of any halachic writings on this idea.